# Jax-Rs Security Annotations : Missing Interactions with the JEE8 Security API ?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

i have issues when trying out the new jee8 security api
(https://github.com/andrebiegel/jax-rs-playground.git  take the jee8 branch )
When I declare the security-contraints with jax-rs annotations  (PermitAll, RolesAllowed) on a jax-rs resource , the `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` doesn't protects the resources. it only works when defining the constraints via web.xml.

I would like to define the constraints by annotations.

how does that work ? Other annotations ? I also testet that with a @DeclaredRoles/ @RolesAllowed combination

Comment: Can you give a link to where you found that this is something that should work out of the box with EE 8?

Comment: @peeskillet actually , I have to confess, that i didn't read anything about that and the reference implementation also does not point to that direction (https://github.com/javaee/security-soteria/tree/master/test/app-jaxrs).. But.. this jax-rs annotations declare RBAC and the new api offers a simplified Security API , so it was just an intuitive conclusion ... don't  misunderstand me , the answer : works as designed, is a totally valid option